# How do I prevent my custom Slack emojis from shrinking when uploaded?

Tags: slack, emoji

I am trying to upload this image to Slack's custom emoji feature:

[image: SpideyTwins]

When I go to upload this image as a custom Slack emoji, the image becomes shrunk and surrounded with a dark background, making the image hard to see.

[image: What happens when I try to upload]

I've tried many things, including using different file formats and shrinking the image to lesser and lesser size. Currently, the image is in PNG format and is 150x150 pixels, yet it still will not work.

How can I maximize the custom emoji space for new emojis?

Answer (score 2):

The uploading doesn't really shrink the image, but it is actually showing examples of how it will look on a white or black background, depending on the theme you're using.
Once it is uploaded it'll have the original size.
It will add a thin border when you hover over it.